# Where is Angular's architecture inspired from?

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, frontend

After some time working with Angular, I came to ask myself:

**How did their developers came to build something so far from a natural/other framework JS paradigm?**

They've introduced:

- `$scopes` and imbricated `$scopes`
- inline-html triggers (`ng-click="methodCall()"`)
- `$digest` cycles
- special formated components (`$window`, `$document`, etc.)
- name-dependant parameter accessing (`function($scope, $element)` is equivalent to `function($element, $scope)`)
- etc.

All those things that make the [angular learning-curve famously steep](https://dzone.com/articles/why-angularjs-known-have-steep), and confuses a lot developpers that have been working with [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/), [Ember](http://emberjs.com/), or now I'd even say [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/).

My unverified conclusion is that this architecture is inspired from **software development architecture** (like Java). Unfortunately (or not? ^^) I don't know a thing about this part of the programming world.

Does anyone has more info/perspective on this?

Comment: Angular is based on the Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) paradigm that promotes separation of concerns between the presentation and the data. Things like `$window`, `$http`, etc... are injectable services that were created to adhere to Dependency Injection (DI) principles.

Comment: One important aspect of Angular is that it was designed with testability in mind. You can search YouTube for "The Clean Code Talks" videos by Misko Hevery (creator of Angular) to get more understanding on what inspired testability-related Angular concepts.

Comment: Question has been well documented by the developers. Personally I adopted using angular after going through their [phonecat tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) and it seemed intuitive to me. The term `confuses developers` is very subjective. If it's so confusing why such a high adoption rate?